# `lookupviewservice` eats a lot memory

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dictionary

After a while, `lookupviewservice` will occurred and use more than 2G memory (even more than this after a few days). I have to end the process manually, but after a while, it comes up again, even though I have never used the `Dictionary` app.

What is this caused by? There might be memory leakage with this app, but how can I prevent this?

My laptop is Macbook Pro with 10.10.2.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. As I don't care about the Dictionary lookup service I disabled it. In System Preferences : Trackpad : Point & Click, I unchecked "Lookup & data detectors" and also "Force click and haptic feedback". Then I force quit the LookupViewService processes which Activity Monitor showed using a lot of Real Mem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is the osx feature,search what is the word means in Dictionary by click 3 fingers.
I think it's a bug of 10.10